# Change the way camera looks at object

Tags: three.js

Im working on an app which uses THREE js for animations
and have a trouble with the camera

what i need is to change the way camera looks at scene
now it looks from the outside to inside of the scene
i need to change it to opposite, so the camera looks from the center to the border of the scene

is this really possible?

Here is sandbox with my code https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-mahavira-tur31?fontsize=14

Thanks!

Comment: If you want the camera to look from the center, why don't you simply set the camera position to something really close to the center? For example: `camera.position.set(0, 0, 0.00001);`

Comment: I'd take a step back and learn what it means working with `Object3D`. If you can do something to a box, you can do it to a camera.

Comment: @Marquizzo - if I set camera position to the center of the scene (its actully default camera position) - camera still look to the center, but I need it to look in opposite direction (

Comment: @pailhead - That`s the point, I was searching in documentation, but no luck for now.  Could you please consult what exactly should I search for?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, looks like solved.
The thing was that I used camera-controls package to move/rotate camera and that package blocks native camera.lookAt() and uses its own method